# Qt QSystemTrayIcon change menu items

Tags: python, qt, menu, pyqt, system-tray

I am using Pyqt however c++ code is fine. I am trying to change a menu item in QSystemTrayIcon using the QT framework in Linux (Ubuntu 11.10). Currently I have tried to reset the QMenu that I initially set:

```
self.tray = QSystemTrayIcon()
m = QMenu()
m.addAction('First')
m.addAction('Second')
tray.setContextMenu(m)
```

I place this in my class and make tray a class variable. I was thinking that if I just change the tray to set a new menu it would update:

```
new_m = QMenu()
new_m.addAction('First')
new_m.addAction('Third')
self.tray.setContextMenu(new_m)
```

However that doesn't work and the tray menu is still the same as it was initially made. How could I be able to rebuild the menu to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested with the following code and it seems to work fine :

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

    self.tray = QSystemTrayIcon(QApplication.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_DriveDVDIcon), self)
    m = QMenu()
    m.addAction('First')
    m.addAction('Second')
    self.tray.setContextMenu(m)
    self.tray.show()

    p = QPushButton("test", self)
    self.setCentralWidget(p)
    p.clicked.connect(self.onClick)

  def onClick(self):
    new_m = QMenu()
    new_m.addAction('First')
    new_m.addAction('Third')
    self.tray.setContextMenu(new_m)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainWindow()
w.show();
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Are you sure there is only one `QSystemTrayIcon` object ? (In your snippets, there is both `self.tray` and `tray`).

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I had to hide the tray and then show it and then set a new context menu for it to show up. Maybe it has to do something with my setup.

Comment: Having exactly the same problem, the code above is not working in my case as with my own application :-| I am on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.